# Extending QML ApplicationWindow in C++

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-quick

How can you properly extend the QML ApplicationWindow type? According to the documentation, ApplicationWindow instantiates a QQuickWindow. So I tried sub classing from QQuickWindow and exposing the type to QML as MyWindow. The problem is that MyWindow doesn't actually extend the QML type ApplicationWindow, so you don't get all the properties like menuBar and toolBar. How can I extend ApplicationWindow in C++ and expose it to QML? Here is what I'm currently doing:

```
class MyQuickWindow : public QQuickWindow
{
    //...irrelevant additions
}


int main()
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    qmlRegisterType<MyQuickWindow>("MyExtensions", 1, 0, "MyApplicationWindow");

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

Here is the QML file:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import MyExtensions 1.0

MyApplicationWindow {
    width: 800
    height: 600
    visible: true

    menuBar: MenuBar {    // ERROR: menuBar is not a property
        Menu {
            title: "File"
            MenuItem { text: "New" }
            MenuItem { text: "Open" }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I need to have my own additions in C++ to the QQuickWindow for other reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the job for [qmlRegisterType](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#qmlRegisterType). And it is a bit hard to say if you miss something with your C++ part but registering the type should help. That is for exposing the type itself and should enable the derived QQuickWindow functionality (derived from ApplicationWindow actually). But for what you are adding you need to deal with [Q_PROPERTY](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/properties.html) and Q_INVOKABLE (which is for functions) mechanism. See the whole bunch of Q_* QObject macro.

And if that was not enough then there is an example for such [inheritance](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-referenceexamples-coercion-example.html).

Correction: the author is dealing with QML-made type but he can still try to mimic the type on his own. The path to ApplicationWindow.qml source code is: C:\Qt\5.3\Src\qtquickcontrols\src\controls where C:\Qt\5.3\ is the root for selected Qt version.I would attempt that and that is feasible unless we want to find out about explicit QML inheritance. That file can also be found at Qt source code [repository](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtquickcontrols/source/960a78ae6231767a34a6e4de76bf4fa28ff401f1:src/controls/ApplicationWindow.qml).

Comment: Yeah, I've used qmlRegisterType to register the custom QQuickWindow type. The problem is how can I add the functionality that is provided with QtQuick.Controls.ApplicationWindow.

Comment: Firs off, as long as properties resolved run-time it should inherit all the functionality from QtQuick.Controls.ApplicationWindow exposed to QML. Second, you may add new functionality and expose it via q_properties or so.

Comment: Ok, but the problem is there isn't any ApplicationWindow class to inherit from in C++. ApplicationWindow is a QML type, derived from Window (QML), which instantiates a QQuickWindow (C++). In my example, MyQuickWindow (C++) inherits from QQuickWindow (C++), but now we don't have anything associated with the ApplicationWindow (QML). In the Qt example "Extending QML - Inheritance and Coercion" you link, the Person type which is being extended is a user created type. I'm trying to extend ApplicationWindow, which has no C++ backbone which I'm aware of.

Comment: Right, I found that in Qt sources: C:\Qt\5.3\Src\qtquickcontrols\src\controls\ApplicationWindow.qml You can just copy it and adjust for your own needs (?)

Comment: You can use MaintenanceTool for downloading Qt source code if so.

Comment: Ok, so I ended up just copying the base logic inside of ApplicationWindow.qml. Ideally I would have liked to reuse the existing functionality from ApplicationWindow, but this isn't too bad.